# visual studio is running, but localhost can't connect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I have vs 2015, and a asp.net mvc 5 website. It was running fine until a while back, but just today I noticed it stopped working. When I start debugging, visual studio is running fine, and so is IIS Express, but localhost page cannot be found.

This is what my IIS Express.

[image: IIS Express]

And the visual studio

[image: Visual studio 2015]

And the browser

[image: localhost]

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Things I've tried, which didn't help:

1) Reinstall (clean) IIS Express 10
2) Deleted the folder `C:\Users\Razor\Documents\IISExpress` so that when visual studio is restarted, it creates the folder again.
3) Deleted the Solution folder's `.vs` directory (that contains the applicationhost.config) and it was re-created again.

None of the above methods have worked. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong in here?

Comment: Try to change the port and re start the web site

Comment: Have you maybe changed the code in your `RouteConfig.cs` or removed the Controller or Controller action which is setup as the default in your RouteConfig?

Comment: try deleting the .sou file also

Comment: I recently installed VS2017 and copied all of my projects from Documents/Visual Studio 15/Projects to Documents/Visual Studio 17/Projects and started to receive this issue.

To fix it, I had to update the application path (within the Visual Studio 17 folder) of the project within .vs/config/applicationhost.config, under the <sites> declaration.

Comment: Any solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: It *did* connect, that's why the error displayed in the browser is "404" and not "connection refused" or "host unreachable".

Comment: look in the browser dev tools network tab and inspect the response. Make sure it is actually served by IIS (you see that in a response header), I once had the problem that http.sys hogged the port and handled the request instead of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Close **IIS EXPRESS** and try again

**EDIT** : 
I know that this sound a little bit crazy but try to disable Firewall and re-enable it. This is working for me.

Comment: explain more to new comers

Comment: When running the application from vs studio, IIS Express starts (
the small icon at the bottom right of the screen). Try to close the IIS Express from the icon -> Stop Debugging the app from vs studio -> Run the app from vs studio

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem , after lots of efforts like deleting IIS profile , adding firewall rules and opening vs in administrator mode and many other.... 
i found solution. 
1) Stop all those application who uses IIS 
2) Edit file  %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\ApplicationHost.config. 
 
3) find your solution name inside of all registred sites

```xml
<system.applicationHost> 
<sites>
    <site name="YourSolutionName" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="YourApplicationPoolName">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="YourSolutionPath" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
</sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

Confirm Port number in bindingInformation. 
4) Now go to your visual studio. 
5) Right click on solution -> Go to properties -> Inside Web tab set Project URL : http://localhost:1234/
also check Override application root URL check box. Set this URL also http://localhost:1234/   
6)Save this and run application. 
**Note :**  While changing ApplicationHost.config file you found multiple instances of your code. you have to find latest port and update it with your port number.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to repair IIS Express 10 (Or the version you got) from the control panel

Comment: this assumes you have access to iisexpress_amd64_en-US.msi ?
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767169/visual-studio-2017-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-chrome

Answer (score -3):

Please follow the below step:

1. Remove the directory %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress.
2. Delete the applicationhost.config file which is placed within the .vs\Config\ folder 
   in your Visual Studio project root folder.
3. Restart the Visual Studio with run as Administrator.
4. Run the your project.