# Visual Studio 2017 Failed to launch debug adapter 'chrome'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I have a asp.net mvc 5 project.
When I try to start debugging with enabled Script debugging mode, and using Chrome, the Visual studio 2017 shows the error:

[image]

It works when I set 'Enable legacy Chrome JavaScript debugger for ASP.NET' in Visual Studio debugging options:

[image]

But how can I solve this issue without enabling legacy Chrome JavaScript debugger?

Comment: I removed Visual Studio 2017, installed VS 2019, then reinstall VS 2017, and it works

Comment: I have been getting this on a nearly new .net 5 web app, VS 2019, debugging with IIS Express. It seems to happen when  I add lines in Startup.ConfigureServices(), and once it starts happening, I have to reboot the machine to make it go away. Restarting Visual, returning to a working commit, deleting .vs, nothing less than a reboot seems to work. This could really finally drive me nuts.

Answer (score 118):

I've found it's easiest to never use JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio. In my honest opinion, the [Chrome JavaScript debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) is a much better alternative for debugging.

To turn off debugging and fix the error in VS2019, go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General. Uncheck the following option:

[image]

Comment: >Chris, Thanks, this is a straight forward answered for VS 2019. It works like charm.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks so much. This has been plaguing me forever and your fix works perfectly.

Comment: Never had a problem with VS 2019, till this morning. Unchecking Javascript debugging worked for me.

Comment: If you still want to have VS debugger linked to your JS file, you can refresh your IIS Express as in my case it forced iisExpress to open on a project on the wrong port.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182304/visual-studio-is-running-but-localhost-cant-connect?form=MY01SV&OCID=MY01SV

Comment: this also worked for me, however I dont see why this is causing an issue, since it only ever appears to happen when switch btwn git branches when inside vs

Answer (score 11):

delete .vs folder from project folder

Answer (score 9):

For me it worked when I closed all the instances of the browser and re-run.

Comment: I had a browser window that opened up on another screen that I couldn't see while using remote desktop.

Answer (score 4):

I just unchecked the option. It's working for me:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Following trick work for me

- click on browser selector and disable the script debugging
  [image: Disable script debugging]

Comment: This worked for me, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue that the Microsoft people has put on the back burner.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/641639/failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-for-google-chrome-o.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many variations of this error being asked about all over.  Since this is the top of my search engine I'll answer here:

I had installed another file editor (Code Writer) that set itself as the default program for a whole host of files that were previously set to Visual Studio.  Between a combination of **doing a VS Installer Repair, and manually changing other associations back to VS, and a reboot**, it's working for me again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for Visual Studio 2019 in chrome browser, it was loading empty, and in edge browser, it was trying to open some file from local.

1. I unchecked(toggled) `Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.Net`
2. Closed the browsers.
3. Removed the `.vs` folder from the root solution directory (this step may not be required)
4. Built the solution.

It started working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked if I just unchecked the option -> build, then I checked it again.

Comment: This may look like a bad answer. But it fixed it for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked the **Build** tab, then clicked **Build Solution**. No more error and the solution ran  fine after.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and attempted the above but it didn't resolve the issue. I had to repair  visual studio using the visual studio installer to fix the problem.