# "Failed to launch debug adapter" when using x86 with Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to debug Blazor WebAssembly App with ASP.NET hosted (Just basic template app) in x86.
App is normally running in case I use x64 platform for debugging. But if I switch all projects (Server,Client and Shared) to x86, and I start debugging, application do not load. It freezes on 12 MB of process memory and then i will get error

Failed to launch debug adapter.
Unable to launch browser

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMmlA.png)

I am testing this with basic template to limit inpact of my code. I need 32 bit app, because I need to get data from old ODBC driver that is only 32 bit.

update:

I have tried to run server without debugging

If using x64 I can access web

If using x84 I receive following error

HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 Failed to launch debug adapter 'chrome'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767169/visual-studio-2017-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-chrome)

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately no.
It is happening only when i try to force x86. Otherwise it is working correctly.

Comment: It is related to the `inspectUri` in `launchSettings.json`. I don't know how to solve it yet, but I am getting the same issue as you

Comment: For me it turned out that my SSL port was out of the acceptable range. Seems like the `launchSettings.json` file has a lot to do with this error as well. [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349412/unable-to-debug-blazor-hosted-webassembly-3-2-0-from-visual-studio-2019-16-6-2)

Comment: It is really problem with debugging. If I publish code it is working normally.
Right now problem is not occurring every time I try to debug, but occasionally and restarting Visual Studio helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing sdk 32 bit in your system.
You can download the last version via this link:
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/f3ab5b2d-90a2-4235-ba83-b431af07cf08/a79a3138bbacde2e44341de3fe89242a/dotnet-sdk-5.0.101-win-x86.exe

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio 2019 16.8.5 - Installing the SDK 32 bit fixed it for me immediately.  I tried installing the 64 bit SDK first assuming that would be correct for my system but I was wrong - you need the 32bit version.